# How to get functions to have the same relative mean of derivate variation?

Tags: time-series, normalization

I have 2 times series and want to normalize the derivate of one of them onto the other. What I want to normalize is the relative mean (relative to the corresponding value of the function) of the variation of the function.

In other words I need to find coef such as : 
`mean(abs(coef*f'/f)) = mean(abs(g'/g))` any idea how to do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by derivate?  I don't recognize that as an English word.

Comment: The first differences are directly proportional to the derivative: standardize them.